# Python: Call child method inside parent method from child method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to be able to recycle a method from a parent class that uses a second method in that parent class. However the second method is overridden in the child class. I want the recycled parent method to use the new overridden second method when it is called from the child class. An example of how I want it to work will hopefully make this clearer:

```
class Parent:
    def method1(self, num):
        return num**2
    def method2(self, list_size):
        return [self.method1(i) for i in range(list_size)] #List of squares

class Child(Parent):
    def method1(self, num): #Overrides corresponding parent method
        return num**3
    def method2(self, list_size):
        return super().method2(list_size) #Returns a list of cubes using child's method 1.
```

Is this possible in python3? Or will calling the parent's method 2 also use the parent's method 1? I'm hoping to reuse large parts of a parent class as the child class differs in only a few ways. The methods nesting like that in the parent class make it a lot more general.

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to test it with simple code! It does work like I wanted if anyone was wondering!

Comment: ... have you tried it and checked?

Comment: Lol no, I just thought up that quick example whilst typing out this question. Just tried it. It does work like I want it to. DOH! Thanks for taking the time to point that out!

Comment: I was about to post a comment saying: Sure, `child().method2([1])` returns `[1]`, right? And then I realized that a list made up of only 1s and 0s is probably not a good way to test whether you're squaring or cubing the numbers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works the way you want it to.

You can easily test this yourself. Unless you pass in nothing but 0s and 1s, it should be pretty obvious whether they're getting squared or cubed.

And, in cases where it's less obvious, just add a debugger breakpoint to `Child.method1` and `Parent.method1` and see which one gets hit. Or add `print(f'Child1.method({self}, {num})')` to the method and see if it gets printed out.

---

If you're coming from another language with C++ OO semantics instead of Smalltalk OO semantics, it may help to think of it this way: Every method is always virtual.

- Are `__init__` calls virtual? Yes.
- What if you call a method during `__init__`? Yes.
- What if you call a method inside a `super` call? Yes.
- What about a `@classmethod`? Yes.
- What if…? Yes.

The only exceptions are when you go out of your way to explicitly tell Python *not* to make a virtual function call:

- Calls on `super()` use the implementation from the next class in the MRO chain, because that's the whole point of `super`.
- If you grab a parent's bound method and call that, like `Parent.method1(self, num)`, you obviously get `Parent.method1`, because that's the whole point of bound methods.
- If you go digging into the class dicts and run the descriptor protocol manually, you obviously get whatever you do manually.

---

If you're not trying to understand Python in terms of Java, and just want a deeper understanding of Python on its own terms, what you need to understand is what happens when you call `self.method1(i)`.

First, `self.method1` doesn't know or care that you're going to call it. It's an attribute lookup, just like, say, `self.name` would be.

The way Python resolves this is described in the [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), but an oversimplified version looks like this:

- Does `self.__dict__` have anything named `method1`? No.
- Does `type(self).__dict__` have anything named `method1`? Yes.

  - Return `type(self).__dict__['method1'].__get__(self)`.

If that second lookup failed, Python would loop over `type(self).mro()` and do the same test for each one. But here, that doesn't come up. `type(self)` is always going to be `Child` for an instance of `Child`, and `Child.__dict__['method1']` exists, so it binds `Child.method` to `self`, and the result is what `self.method1` means.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I now understand a lot more! Running my example code (which I somehow didn't think to do) shows me that what you're saying is correct too! Accepted!

Comment: Can I achieve the opposite behaviour, in particular with classmethods? I want to enhance a child class method using its base functions, so when I call the super().method2 I want it to also call the parent's method1 and not the child's method1.

Comment: @GeorgeMoutsopoulos I have the same question that you did.  I see that no one answered it here.  Did you find a way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: yes.
Just tried a slightly modified version of your code with prints.

```
class Parent:
    def method1(self):
        print("Parent method1")

    def method2(self):
        print("Parent method2")
        self.method1()


class Child(Parent):
    def method1(self):
        print("Child method1")

    def method2(self):
        print("Child method2")
        super().method2()


c = Child()
c.method2()
```

This is the output:

```
Child method2

Parent method2

Child method1
```

As you can see, the method1 used is the child one.